# Vanishing of local cohomology $\operatorname{H}^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))=0$

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

Let $M$ be a module over Noetherian ring $R$ such that $\operatorname{H}^1_I(M)=0$ for every ideal $I$ of $R$. Show that $\operatorname{H}^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))=0$ for every ideal $J$.

I tried to prove it by Mayer-Vietoris sequence but  I can't, unfortunately. Also applied the following sequences
$$0‎\rightarrow \Gamma_I(M)‎\rightarrow M‎\rightarrow D_I(M)‎\rightarrow 0 $$ 
$$0‎\rightarrow \Gamma_I(M)‎\rightarrow M ‎\rightarrow M/\Gamma_I(M)‎\rightarrow0 .$$
Moreover, since $\operatorname{H}^1_I(M)=0$ for every ideal $I$ of $R$ then Proposition 4.1.3 from Brodmann-Sharp, *Local Cohomology*, suggests that $\operatorname{H}^i_I(M)=0$ for all $i\geq 0$.

**Background**: $D_I(M)$ means ideal transform with respect to $I$ and the first exact sequence obtains from Theorem 2.2.4(i)(c) in the same book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch of proof:**

Let $J=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. If $J\subseteq I$ it's done. Let $J‎\nsubseteq‎ I$ therefore $\exists x\in J-I $. By 4.1.22 from the same book we have the following exact sequence
$$0‎\rightarrow‎ \Gamma_{I+x}(M)‎\rightarrow‎\Gamma_I(M)‎\rightarrow‎ \Gamma_I(M_x)‎\rightarrow‎ 0=H^1_{I+x}(M).$$ 
Applying $\Gamma_J(-)$ we get 
$$ \cdots‎\rightarrow‎ \Gamma_J(\Gamma_I(M_x))‎\rightarrow‎ H^1_J(\Gamma_{I+x}(M))‎\rightarrow‎ H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))‎\rightarrow‎ H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M_x))‎\rightarrow‎\cdots $$ 
Now use the independence Theorem
$$\Gamma_J(\Gamma_I(M_x))\cong \Gamma_J(\Gamma_{I_x}(M_x))\cong \Gamma_J(\Gamma_I{(M )})_x\cong \Gamma_{J_x}(\Gamma_I(M))_x=0. ~ (Since~  x\in J)$$
$$H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M_x))\cong H^1_J(\Gamma_{I_x}(M_x))\cong H^1_J(\Gamma_I{(M )})_x\cong H^1_{J_x}(\Gamma_I(M))_x=0.~ (Since~ x\in J)$$
Therefore $H^1_J(\Gamma_{I+x}(M))‎\cong‎ H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))$.
Continuing as before we have 
$$H^1_J(\Gamma_I(M))\cong H^1_J(\Gamma_{I+J}(M))‎=0. ~(Since~ J\subseteq I+J)$$